# Use ID from one page in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic HTML in my page.
Now i want to use Id and data from one Js file to Other.

I have following HTML in `care.js` file

```
$('#chat-box').html(
   '<p style="margin-top:10px;">Enter Your Name</p><input type="text" id="chat-box-name"  class="chat-editing" />'
                   );
```

Now i want to use the data entered in above input box in `chat.js`.

Is it possible that i can usethe `id/data` from one JS file to other in same project??

Thanks

Comment: As long as the second JavaScript file is added below this one and the inputboxes are added to the DOM when the code from the chat.js is executed everything should work fine.

Comment: @MarkNijboer But how do i fetch the data ??

Answer (score 2):

When this code executes you will have a element with your code as child:

```
<div id="chat-box">
  <p style="margin-top:10px;">Enter Your Name</p>
  <input type="text" id="chat-box-name"  class="chat-editing" />
</div>
```

If you make sure the code from the second JavaScript file only gets executed after you added the content to #chat-box you can use JavaScript to get the value of the inputbox. Assuming that you use jQuery, like you did in your question:

```
var input = $('#chat-box-name').val(); //The input
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('chat-box-name').value;
```

Comment: I already tried that,but to no avail... Will give it one more try

Comment: Remove var from var input = $('#chat-box-name').val();   Because if you want to use input in another file.we have to make it global.if we remove var ,then input variable becomes global.

Comment: yes,try with this  inputtext = $('#chat-box-name').val(); change name of variable. as input is html tag

Comment: Yeah i already used different name. And it should be declared at very top of other js file